# Apache2 ignores virtual hosts

Tags: magento, apache2, virtualhost

I'm really stuck on this. I have a magento installation and an apache2 server. Because of multistore I need to map some domains like this:

```
/var/www/magento             -> Magento installation
/var/www/magento/bienenkorb  -> store1
/var/www/magento/sarto24     -> store2
```

if I get there over ip everything works fine:

http://91.250.115.212/magento/bienenkorb/ leads to the first store

http://91.250.115.212/magento/sarto24/ leads to the second store

Now I mapped a domain (temporary) http://bienenkorb24.eu to the IP 91.250.115.212

Then I created a bienenkorb24.eu.conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-avalable and activated it via a2ensite, containing:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/magento/bienenkorb
    ServerRoot /var/www/magento/bienenkorb
    ServerName bienenkorb24.eu
    <Directory /var/www/magento/bienenkorb>
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But I still land on the root(/var/www) instead of the store1 adress.

Can somebody help me?

No special errors in error.log:

```
Tue Jul 21 19:51:08 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Jul 21 19:51:08 2015] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Jul 21 19:51:08 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) DAV/2 mod_perl/2.0.7 Perl/v5.14.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 21 19:51:11 2015] [error] [client 66.249.64.224] File does not exist: /var/www/gmundner
```

Comment: could you check your apache2 error logs? e.g. somewhere located in /var/log (and post anything of possible relevance here ;) )

Comment: error.log files attached :)

Comment: Did you **reload** the Apache web service?

Comment: Yes, several times. Hanging on it for hours :-/

Comment: ok - strange so far. How does your httpd.conf look? did you mention your .eu domain there? are you sure that your bienenkorb24.eu.conf is included?

Comment: Try putting your definition at the bottom of your httpd.conf file and restarting apache.  If it works, then that means your `bienenkorb24.eu.conf` file isn't being loaded.  Make sure you're including that file in your httpd.conf file.

Comment: httpd.conf is empty. but does it matter? because apache2.conf contains "Include sites-enabled/", and in sites-enabled folder is a symbolik link to the conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code;

```
sudo gedit /etc/hosts
Add  this 127.0.0.1  bienenkorb24.eu #You can use your ip here

cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf


Add following 
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName bienenkorb24.eu 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bienenkorb24 

    <Directory /var/www/html/bienenkorb24> 
        DirectoryIndex index.php 
        AllowOverride All 
        Order allow,deny 
        Allow from all 
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>

apachectl configtest
sudo a2ensite bienenkorb24.eu 
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 reload
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/bienenkorb24/
chmod -R a+w /var/www/html/bienenkorb24/
```

Change the folder paths to suit your needs, wherever necessary. If one works fine do same for other domains.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: did u make change in the core_config_data ? after changing the urls in table, be sure to delete var/cache, var/session and browser cache and then check.

Comment: uh, no, I can't remember changing this file. where can I find it?

Comment: core_config_data is a table , you will get it in your magento database. you will get the details of your magento site database in /var/www/magento/bienenkorb/app/etc/local.xml file .. Check this link https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-change-magento-base-urls.html

Comment: I checked it, the table contains the correct secure and  unsecure urls: web/unsecure/base_url - http://bienenkorb24.eu/

Comment: ok usually these are the steps by which it starts working. i tried my self and its working at my end.